# Unreadable text in Google Docs in Firefox on Gnome Dark Mode

Tags: firefox

[image: Screenshot of the problem. Name and middle part removed.]

In Google Docs, I cannot see the text in comments as it is written in black on very dark gray. The title of a document is also displayed strangely.
Similar issues occur on other web pages.

The issues occur both when I use the standard Firefox appearance and with FT Deep Dark 14.0.

I use Firefox 44.0.2 on GNOME Shell 3.18.3 with the GTK+ theme `Adwaita-Dark-3.14-rev.2` on Arch Linux 4.4.1-2.

P.S.: I added a screenshot, I covered the user with a red box and removed the middle part of the image to fit the screen.

Comment: If it's happening on other pages it sounds like it's a browser/OS issue, not a web application issue.

Comment: A screenshot would help. Also, are webfonts (options-->content-->advanced) turned on or off?

Answer (score 4):

I run into the same issue and solved it with the instructions from this post https://www.dovydasvenckus.com/linux/2018/08/20/fix-firefox-dark-input-fields-on-gnome/

Basically:

1. Enter`about:config` in the URL
2. Right click -> New String.
3. Name `widget.content.gtk-theme-override` value `Adwaita:light`
4. Restart Firefox